# Querying twitter streaming api keywords from a database

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, tweepy

I'm filtering the twitter streaming API by tracking for several keywords.

If for example I only want to query and return from my database tweet information that was filtered by tracking for the keyword = 'BBC' how could this be done?

Do the tweet information collected have a key:value relating to that keyword by which it was filtered?

I'm using python, tweepy and MongoDB.

Would an option be to search for the keyword in the returned json 'text' field? Thus generate a query where it searches for that keyword = 'BBC' in the text field of the returned json data?

Comment: Can you elaborate? (Possibly with an example)?  What does "have a key:value relating to that keyword by which it was filtered" mean?

Comment: I mean, say for example I'm doing filter(track=[BBC]). Then in the json returned is their a value like 'track:BBC'? We can track upto 400 keywords and if you're storing this in storage and in the future only want to retrive that information by keyword how else could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Twitter API doesn't provide a way to do this. You can try searching through receive tweets for the keywords you specified, but it might not match exactly.